# How to get and change Public IP in Python?

Tags: python, proxy, ip

I have been trying to get the live IP address in python and change it using a proxy server. The code I have seen is for local IP not the Public IP.

How can I get public IP using python? i.e. the IP I get from [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/), and can change the public IP using a proxy request in Python on windows.

Comment: You can use `requests` or `urllib` for HTTP requests or [PySocks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySocks) for more protocols. if you want to set a system proxy go to network > proxy and type the ip of the proxy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple services you can use to get your ip. The one I use mostly is `ipinfo.io/ip`

You can use below code

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://<IP>:<PORT>',
  'https': 'http://<IP>:<PORT>',
}

req = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/ip', proxies=proxies)
print (req.text)
```

Comment: How this ip can be changed ?

Comment: Putting your proxy details in `proxies` variable will change the public IP. So you need use proxies to change your public IP address

Comment: @pajarnas, what doesn't work? If you see the same IPs then the proxy could also be a transparent proxy and your IP is still exposed

Answer (score 1):

You can also retrieve your public ip using [ident](https://ident.me):

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://ident.me')
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"IP >>> {response.content.decode('utf8')}")
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can get public ip address using [hek](https://pypi.org/project/hek/).

```
import hek

# get ip 
ip = hek.ipstuff.myip(find="query")

# print ip
print(ip)
```